# How do I access the Processor power management options in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, power-management

While Googling I found that to make my computer more silent I could set it in the Processor power management options overview.

Unfortunately, I don't see it at:
[image]

Was it moved somewhere else? How do I set it?

Answer (score 2):

You can [enable some of these settings](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/configure-hidden-power-options-in-windows-10/), but only do this on your own PC. *If this is a managed corporate PC, IT has purposely hidden these using Group Policies or Registry changes!*

First, check *Policies* in Regedit to see if it's hidden, and if so, change it:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Power\PowerSettings
```

It is also possible to edit the settings under the following keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Power\PowerSettings
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings
```

To reveal Processor Performance threshold options, at an elevated CMD prompt, enter

```
- powercfg -attributes SUB_PROCESSOR 12a0ab44-fe28-4fa9-b3bd-4b64f44960a6 -ATTRIB_HIDE
```

and

```
- powercfg -attributes SUB_PROCESSOR 06cadf0e-64ed-448a-8927-ce7bf90eb35d -ATTRIB_HIDE
```

You can also [change settings from the CMD prompt](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-8.1-and-8/hh825694(v=win.10)). To list current settings:

```
powercfg -QUERY
```

Then find the GUID for that setting and change it. For example, I found the following information for the *Minimum processor state*:

```
Subgroup GUID: 54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00  (Processor power management)
GUID Alias: SUB_PROCESSOR
Power Setting GUID: 893dee8e-2bef-41e0-89c6-b55d0929964c  (Minimum processor state)
  GUID Alias: PROCTHROTTLEMIN
  Minimum Possible Setting: 0x00000000
  Maximum Possible Setting: 0x00000064
  Possible Settings increment: 0x00000001
  Possible Settings units: %
Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000002
Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000002
```

Using the GUID or the alias, PROCTHROTTLEMIN, this can be changed to a value between 0 and 64.